# How to change the database drupal forms send to

Tags: forms, database

It's super easy using php and SQL but how do you change the default database drupal 6 saves posted data in the forms? To an external database?

Comment: I feel your question is so generic. Can you explain more!! which forms are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Ate you talking about the Webforms module or just forms in general?

Comment: Hi sorry.     function semicontacts_form_submit($form_id, &$form_data){
    db_query("INSERT INTO drupalsemicontacts (firstname, lastname, phonenumber) VALUES

Comment: Hi sorry. This is an example of the query that submits the data to the DB. It automatically knows the default database drupal is installed into and submits it to that DB + (table name), and i can only specify the table name here?         function names_form_submit($form_id, &$form_data){
    db_query("INSERT INTO drupalnamescontacts (firstname, lastname, phonenumber) VALUES

Comment: I did try following [hello world 2] (http://www.semicolon.co.za/mysql_tutorials/create-hello-world-module-drupal6-part2.html) but again it assumes you want to save to the local drupal database. @MPD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try reading through [How to connect to multiple databases within Drupal](https://drupal.org/node/18429) (notably, the Drupal 6 section towards the end.

Basically, in your `settings.php` file, convert the `$db_url` to an array, and add the secondary database:

e.g.

```
$db_url = 'mysql://drupal:drupal@localhost/drupal';
```

becomes

```
$db_url['default'] = 'mysql://drupal:drupal@localhost/drupal';
$db_url['db2'] = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/db2';
```

Then create a submit handler that either compliments or overrides an existing form submit handler and use [`db_set_active`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.inc/function/db_set_active/6) to connect to the secondary database, save the data, and then switch back.

e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_MY_EXTRA_SUBMIT_HANDLER($form, &$form_state){
  // Switch to db2  
  db_set_active('db2');

  // Do all your form processing and database transactions

  // Connect back to default Drupal database
  // *Note* If your primary db is keyed with "default", then you don't need to
  // pass an argument to db_set_active().
  db_set_active('default');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great reply, this was what I was looking for however I didn't realise about the little snag of "This only works with two databases of the same type. For example the following code will not work." I actually have a postgresql DB that I am wanting to input data into. And that is obviously different to the drupal sql. I could reinstall drupal with postgresql as the DB. However this is not possible as the site is fixed and the client will not allow changes to this. Looks like I will have t use php/pgsql/html forms to submit the data.

Comment: Is there any other method other than using my own html/php forms t submit to my postgresql db from within drupal? do any of the other form mobules support submitting to an external DB of different datatype? @Chapabu